# Why is Python 3.8.2 stored in nonstandard place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

My download install of Python 3.8.2-amd64 is stored in:

`C:\Username\AppData\Local\PackageCache\{13ee6ab9-4dca-406c-bc3b-5d86391d39a1}`

**Why is it stored in `PackageCache` rather than `\Python\Python38`?**

I can execute `py` at the command line, but neither `pip` command nor `pip --version` are recognized, so **I can't install pandas, numpy, etc.**

When I try to download `get-pip.py` I get error message `no such site`.

Comment: On my system it's called `get-pip-py3.py`. It's a Python script and already exists, so you don't need to download it. Instead, _execute_ it via `py get-pip-py3.py` from your `\Python\Python38` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have customized the installation when you installed Python on your computer. If you do, it will be installed in C:\Program Files but if you don't, it is installed in your Windows profile so you don't need to have administrative rights to install it.

You can find a [little bit more on this subject](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-full-installer) on the Python documentation site